# Young inequality application

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Can someone please help me to correct the following inequality:

Let $a,b,c$ be three strictely positif numbers

we have :

$a^{\frac{1}{108}}b^{\frac{3}{4}}c^6\le \frac{1}{27}a^{\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{26}{27}(b^{\frac{3}{4}}c^6)^{\frac{27}{26}}=\frac{1}{27}a^{\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{26}{27}(b^{\frac{3}{4}}c^6)^{\frac{1}{26}}(b^{\frac{3}{4}}c^6)=\frac{1}{27}a^{\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{26}{27}(b^{\frac{1}{104}}c^{\frac{3}{13}})(b^{\frac{3}{4}}c^6)$
$\le \frac{1}{27}a^{\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{26}{27}(\frac{6}{13}b^{\frac{1}{16}}+\frac{7}{13}c^{\frac{3}{7}})(b^{\frac{3}{4}}c^6)$

Thus

$a^{\frac{1}{108}}\le \frac{1}{27}\frac{a^{\frac{1}{4}}}{(b^{\frac{3}{4}}c^6)}+\frac{26}{27}(\frac{6}{13}b^{\frac{1}{16}}+\frac{7}{13}c^{\frac{3}
{7}})$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you made a mistake. $\frac{26}{27}(b^{\frac{3}{4}}c^6)^{\frac{1}{26}}=\frac{26}{27}(b^{\frac{3}{104}}c^{\frac{3}{13}}$)

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: can you please help me to correct this inequality also:
$a^\frac{1}{80} b^{\frac{3}{4}} c^6\le \frac{1}{20} a^{\frac{1}{4}} + \frac{19}{20} (b^{\frac{15}{19}} c^{\frac{120}{19}})= \frac{1}{20} a^{\frac{1}{4}} + \frac{19}{20} (b^{\frac{3}{76}} c^{\frac{26}{19}}) b^{\frac{3}{4}} c^6$
$\le \frac{1}{20} a^{\frac{1}{4}} + \frac{19}{20} (\frac{12}{19} b^{\frac{1}{16}} + \frac{7}{19} c^{\frac{26}{7}}) b^{\frac{3}{4}} c^6$